# Insert duplicate records in the same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to take a record from a table, increment one column and insert the record in the same table again.

This is my table for example:

```
TEST(id, name, city)
      1, john, NY
```

I want to select this record and insert it in the same table 1250 times, expected output is:

```
id, name, city
2, john, NY
3, john, NY
4, john, NY
5, john, NY
6, john, NY
7, john, NY
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(10), city varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Its initial contents:

```
SQL> insert into test values (1, 'John', 'NY');

1 row created.
```

Code that adds some more rows:

```
SQL> insert into test
  2  select id + level, name, city
  3  from test
  4  connect by level <= 5;     --> would be 1250 in your case

5 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       CITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John       NY
         2 John       NY
         3 John       NY
         4 John       NY
         5 John       NY
         6 John       NY

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Code you posted as a comment and sample table aren't related in any way. I have no idea which constraint was violated. I suggest you rewrite the question and provide information which might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create your table using an `IDENTITY` column (or, if you are using Oracle 11 or earlier, a `SEQUENCE`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
  id   INTEGER
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT test_id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  city VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

Then insert your row:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (name, city) VALUES ('john', 'NY');
```

*(Note: the `ID` column is auto-generated and you should not include it.)*

Then you can clone your row:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (name, city)
SELECT name, city
FROM   test
WHERE  id = 1
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1249;
```

*(Again, you do not need to do anything for the `ID` column as it will be auto-generated.)*

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | CITY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | john | NY |
> | 2 | john | NY |
> | 3 | john | NY |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | 1249 | john | NY |
> | 1250 | john | NY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f721680f69e8d0cfeb97e29605db662c)*

Comment: @Talib This answer is answering the question you asked for the `TEST` table. You comment appears to relate the an `pos_trans_collection` table with many different columns and constraints and we do not know what the structure is of that table or the constraints on it. It would be better if you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which contains a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statement for that table and the `INSERT` statement for your sample data and the complete error message as you do not get that error for the table in this question and we cannot replicate it.